# Django Rest Framework: how to use OperationHolderMixin?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In the source code of Django Rest Framework`site-packages/rest_framework/permissions.py`, I can see `OperationHolderMixin` class, and children classes `AND`, `OR` and `NOT`.

There's nothing about it in the documentation and I didn't find a sample of a use case. Has anybody ever used those "compositing" classes, and when should I use them?

Comment: You shouldn't. But you may follow this link if you're curious enough https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57517366/django-rest-framework-deep-dive-where-is-it-determined-that-an-enpoint-needs-a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use those classes directly in your code-base, Just use the classes with ***logical expression***

Suppose you have *three* permission classes,

```
class PermissionOne(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        # your logic
        pass


class PermissionTwo(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        # your logic
        pass


class PermissionThree(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        # your logic
        pass
```

Then, you can use these classes in your view as,

```
class MyAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [PermissionOne | PermissionTwo | PermissionThree]
```

---

The expression **`PermissionOne | PermissionTwo | PermissionThree`** creates a ***virtual DRF permission class*** under the hood with respect to the ***logical expression*** we used.

Which means, you can use rewrite the code as,

```
MyCompositePermissionClass = PermissionOne | PermissionTwo | PermissionThree


class MyAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [MyCompositePermissionClass]
```

**Note:** DRF supports `&` (and), `|` (or) and `~` (not) bitwise operators to create composite permission classes.